# Time series notation

Tags: math-mode, scientific-notation

How can I write this in latex?

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us what you've tried so far.

Comment: This is pretty straightforward. What part are you struggling with? Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 2):

As starting point at construct your document example can serve the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{R_{PF,t+1-\tau}\right\}_{\tau=1}^m 
    \equiv \left\{\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i R_{i,t+1-\tau}\right\}_{\tau=1}^m 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, writing equation by LaTeX is very basic task. I strongly suggest to make yaour self more familiar with latex by reading som introductory text about latex (for example [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX 2ε](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf)) and how to write math expressions (for example [wiki/Mathematic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) and [wiki/Advance_Mathematic](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics)).

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: @e4e5f4, if answer solve your problem, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer :-)